How to Save and Load Color[] very fast without making any copy?
Using WPF:Color, what is the fastest way to save and load ColorTable[] and could it be done without making any copy?
Would be possible to use something similar to:
    Color[] ColorTable = new Color[]
    {
        Colors.Red,
        Colors.Green,
        Colors.Blue,
    };

    File.WriteAllBytes(GetColorTablePath(), ColorTable);
    byte[] bytesColorTable  = File.ReadAllBytes(GetColorTablePath());

I try Span but I have an error saying: "System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot use type 'System.Windows.Media.Color'. Only value types without pointers or references are supported.'" on following code:
  public static void SaveColors()
  {
      Span<Color> colors = _colorTable;
      Span<byte> bytesColorTable = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(colors);
      File.WriteAllBytes(GetColorTablePath(), bytesColorTable.ToArray());
  }


How about serializing the colours like in this question  or this one?

Also, can you explain why you need the 'fastest' way, and what you mean by 'without making any copy'?

Look at the fields in color, what do you think?

@stuartd, I know how to serialize Color. My sample only seriliaze few colors but I need to serialize 50000 colors. That's why I want the fastest way to do it... in order to do it without affecting the user. Also, by preventing to copy data, you should also save a lot of time.

@shingo, Color fields are private which mean I should not try to access them. I know I can do it through reflection but I would prefer to do it thing properly.

I mean the struct has so many fields, do you still expect to save them without making any copy?

@shingo, How can you tell there is many fields? There is many properties. But all byte properties can be backup by only one 32 bits which is reasonably sure (that's how almost computer do). For all float properties, they are only a conversion of byte value to 0 to1 equivalent.

So no matter what, you have to convert these colors one by one and then write these integers into a file. IMO, this process is no different from copying.

@shingo, I thought that with the new Span* And/or Memory* objects and with MemoryMarshall, I could convert the data as a byte array (I mean freeze the array and see it as a bytes array). Then being able to save the byte array directly with File.WriteAllBytes(). It sounds like it is not possible, as far as I understand newly added objects behavior. But my question was to help me clarify if I missed something. Or if there something else I don't know to see the Color array as a byte array (which is really is in memory).

FYI:
I did not find a way to save Color directly without copy. It appears to me that we can't use Span or Memory because the WPF Color type seems to be opaque where the uint field is hidden to the user.
So I did it like that (in wait for a better solution):
    public static Color[]? LoadColors()
    {
        if (File.Exists(GetColorTablePath()))
        {
            byte[] bytesColorTable = File.ReadAllBytes(GetColorTablePath());
            Span<byte> spanTable = bytesColorTable;
            if (spanTable.Length % 4 != 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            Span<uint> spanColors = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, uint>(bytesColorTable);

            Color[] colors = new Color[spanColors.Length];
            for (int index = 0; index < spanColors.Length; index++)
            {
                colors[index] = ColorUtil.FromUInt32(spanColors[index]);
            }

            return colors;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void SaveColors()
    {
        if (ColorTable.Length > 0)
        {
            uint[] uintTable = new uint[ColorTable.Length];
            for (int index = 0; index < ColorTable.Length; index++)
            {
                uintTable[index] = ColorTable[index].ToUInt32();
            }

            Span<uint> uintSpan = new Span<uint>(uintTable);
            Span<byte> bytesTable = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(uintSpan);
            using var file = File.OpenWrite(GetColorTablePath());
            file.Write(bytesTable);
        }
    }

namespace WpfColorGenerator
{
    public static class ColorUtil
    {
        public static uint ToUInt32(byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b)
        {
            return (uint)(a << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b);
        }

        public static uint ToUInt32(this Color color)
        {
            return (uint)(color.A << 24 | color.R << 16 | color.G << 8 | color.B);
        }

        public static void FromUInt32(uint color, out byte a, out byte r, out byte g, out byte b)
        {
            a = (byte)(color >> 24 & 0xFF);
            r = (byte)(color >> 16 & 0xFF);
            g = (byte)(color >> 8 & 0xFF);
            b = (byte)(color & 0xFF);
        }

        public static Color FromUInt32(uint color)
        {
            return Color.FromArgb((byte)(color >> 24 & 0xFF), (byte)(color >> 16 & 0xFF), (byte)(color >> 8 & 0xFF), (byte)(color & 0xFF));
        }
    }
}

